# Comparing strings in Drools using `==` vs `equals()`

Tags: drools

When using `==` operator on input string it does not match opposed to when using `.equals()`.

As the [docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_process_automation_manager/7.7/html/designing_a_decision_service_using_drl_rules/drl-rules-con_drl-rules#patterns_and_constraints) state `==` uses `equals()` internally.

```
Person( firstName == "John" )

// This is similar to the following formats:

java.util.Objects.equals(person.getFirstName(), "John")
"John".equals(person.getFirstName())
```

This is a simple rule example I made

```
rule "String Comparison"

when req:Request()

then

    RuleExecutionResult result = new RuleExecutionResult();
   
    if (req.getPerson().getName().equals("John")) { // If person.name = "John" this is true
        result.setResult("True");
    }
    if (req.getPerson().getName() == "John") { // If person.name = "John" this is false
        result.setResult("False");
    }


    req.getResults().add(result);
end
```

Note that I'm doing the comparison in the `then` part of the rule.
Using `==` in the `when` part of the rule works as expected - matching the name.

What could be the issue?

I'm using [`KIE Server 7.61.0.Final`](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/kie-server-showcase)

Answer (score 0):

Your rule doesn't evaluate both conditions. In an if/else if like you have defined, once the "if" condition is satisfied, the "else if" does not evaluate.

The correct way to design this "rule" would be to track two different results in two different if statements. Something more like:

```
if (req.getPerson().getName().equals("John")) { // test "equals"
    RuleExecutionResult result = new RuleExecutionResult();
    result.SetResult("equals");
    req.getResults().add(result);
} 

if (req.getPerson().getName() == "John") { // test "=="
    RuleExecutionResult result = new RuleExecutionResult();
    result.SetResult("==");
    req.getResults().add(result);
}
```

Of course, this matters little in real applications because you'd nearly never be doing comparisons in the right hand side/rule consequences for a well designed rule base. I can't think of any legitimate scenario where the best practice would recommend doing any comparisons in the 'then' clause. If you find yourself writing an 'if' statement on the RHS, the likely scenario is that you should have two rules.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. It's not the case of if else condition. It behaves like that even when I only have `==` statement.

Regarding the design of the rule, it's a different topic but I want to have rule evaluate the condition and give back response even when the condition does't match and the rule doesn't fire.

Comment: Your use case doesn't make much sense. Have you considered that you might be using the wrong tool for whatever you're trying to do?

Comment: In fact I've considered it. I've read that it's not a good practice to do what I'm doing and I understand it defeats the purpose and the benefits of drools optimisations. Currently these logic exist as javascript functions and we're trying to move to the tool that will give non-developers ability to create new rules and drools seemed a good candidate. Problem is I'm limited with using http api when communicating with server, since we don't want to move to Java world. And another problem is the design of rules, because splitting them would cause a lot of duplication.